# How to reference a view model property in Asp.Net MVC - Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, properties, model

In my razor view, in the "Panel area - to hold the comment button", I am trying to referencing the view models property BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId but I get - "the name BlogPublishedByBlogId does not exist in the current context".

However, I am able to reference the other properties fine using Lamda: model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime

How do I reference the 'blogId' in the "Panel area - to hold the comment button" area?

---

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM

<h2 class="page-header"><span class="blogtitle">@Session["BlogTitle"]</span></h2>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div class="panel panel-default toppanel">

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent, new { @class = "form-control blogContent", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @* Panel area - to hold the comment button. *@
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default Comment" data-id="BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId" value="Comment">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span> Get Comment(s)
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}","commentsBlock", BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId)" style="border: 1px solid #f1eaea; background-color: #eaf2ff;">
        <div class="AddCommentArea" style="margin-left: 30%;  margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">
            <input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "comment", BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId)" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a Comment about the blog..." style="display: inline;" />

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addComment" data-id="BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The view model:

```
namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
   public class BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM
   {
    public BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM()
    {
        this.BlogPublishedByBlogId = new BlogPublishedByBlogId();
    }

    public BlogPublishedByBlogId BlogPublishedByBlogId { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added @Model to the front of:
BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId.